# Checking if values in mysql table are in another table?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables in a mysql database.  The tables are structured like follows:

Table a:

Columns:
id,
name,
intableb

Table b:
Columns:
id,
name

Where the name in table a is part of the value in column name in table b, I want to insert 'true' in column b in table a.  E.g. if there is a value called 'test' in column name in table a, and column name in table b includes a value like 'testing', then table a column intableb should have 'true' in the relevant row.

However what makese this tricky is that there is no suitable join for both tables.
I have no idea how to go about executing this query.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can use Exists instead on any JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_a a
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT name 
FROM Table_b b 
WHERE b.name like N'%'+a.NAME+N'%')
```